# naming a lambda function causing an error in python

Tags: python, lambda

In a groupby, I am using the lambda and I named it so it will be easy to read later. but for some reasone which I don't know this line of code is working

```
  'tradePrice': ['first', np.max, np.min, 'last', lambda x: max(x) - min(x)],
```

But when adding a name for the lambda function, as done here:

```
'tradePrice':['first',np.max, np.min, 'last',('priceRange',lambda x: max(x) - min(x))],
```

I get an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\gilad\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\sorting.py", line
>   446, in safe_sort
>       sorter = values.argsort() TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'str'

The most interesting thing is that on the next few line I do use the same syntax successfully here:

```
  'trade': [('sum', np.sum),('number+trade', lambda x: (x > 0).sum())],
```

If anyone has any idea why the "label" of the lambda is not working in this specific line I will appreciate sharing any idea.
Thanks!

Comment: Did someone (or some reference, or some tool) tell you that you should name your lambda? If so, I suspect that you've misunderstood what it means to name a lambda function: it doesn't mean putting the lambda in a tuple with a string. Instead, you want do to either `priceRange = lambda x: max(x) - min(x)` or `def priceRange(x): return max(x) - min(x)` in a preceding line.

Comment: In any case, we can't answer this question without seeing more of your code. Can you give a minimal, complete and verifiable example ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `lambda` in your working code:

```
'tradePrice': ['first', np.max, np.min, 'last', lambda x: max(x) - min(x)],
```

with a *named* `lambda` would consist of:

```
priceRange = lambda x: max(x) - min(x)

# ...

'tradePrice': ['first', np.max, np.min, 'last', priceRange],
```

the advantage being both readability and the ability to reuse the `lambda` function elsewhere.